# How to show or hide a div if radiobutton of a group is checked or unchecked?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-group

I have a group of radiobuttons, if one button in that group is checked a div appears, if I uncheck the radiobutton the div disappears,

but I didn't get it working that if I check a box the div appears, if I check another the first checked radiobutton will automatically uncheck and the first appeared div will disappear and the 2. div appears.

I try to get that code working. Below is my HTML code:

```
<form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="gruppe1"/>Gruppen</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="group1" id="gruppe2"/>Gruppen 2</label> 
</form>

<div class="layergruppe1">
    <label>Value 1:<input type="number" name="group2" id="value1" value="0" /></label>
    <label>Value 2:<input type="number" name="group2" id="value2" value="0" /></label>
    <label>Value 3:<input type="number" name="group2" id="value3" value="0" /></label>
    <label>Value 4:<input type="number" name="group2" id="value4" value="0" /></label>
</div>

<div class="layergruppe2">
    <label>Value 1:<input type="number" name="group3" id="value1" value="0" /></label>
    <label>Value 2:<input type="number" name="group3" id="value2" value="0" /></label>
    <label>Value 3:<input type="number" name="group3" id="value3" value="0" /></label>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.layergruppe1').hide();
    $("#gruppe1").live("click", function(){
        var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.layergruppe1').show();
        } else {
            $('.layergruppe1').hide();
        }
    });

    $('.layergruppe2').hide();
    $("#gruppe2").live("click", function(){
        var id = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('.layergruppe2').show();
        } else {
            $('.layergruppe2').hide();
        }
    });
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        if (this.previous) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
        this.previous = this.checked;
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EGMdK/87/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EGMdK/121/

Fixed code, hope that helps?

Comment: Sometimes its better to start with a clean code from beginning, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've condensed your code a little:

```
$('.layergruppe1, .layergruppe2').hide();

$('input[name="group1"]').change(
    function(){
        $('div[class^="layergruppe"]').hide();
        $('div.layer' + this.id).show();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EGMdK/122/).

References:

- [attribute-starts-with `[attribute^="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Thank you, [class^="layergruppe"] is new for me but will learn how to use it for further forms and classes :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/gAKYr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.layergruppe1').hide();
$('.layergruppe2').hide();
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(e)
                                  {
        if (this.id == 'gruppe1') {
            $('.layergruppe1').show();
            $('.layergruppe2').hide();
        } else if (this.id == 'gruppe2') {
            $('.layergruppe1').hide();
            $('.layergruppe2').show();
        }  
      });
});
```

other examples...

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/EjJqS/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/Gu63y/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/ftQ8g/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/dW4gD/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/7wdp5/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/7wdp5/

http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/7wdp5/